# Facebook PHP SDK not logging out user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

This is a really frustrating problem (bug?) that I've been trying to figure out. Seems like alot of people complain about the same exact issue, but there's no definite solution or tutorial fixing this issue.

Anyways, my problem is that I can get the SDK to log the user in just fine, however when they click on LogOut. It redirects them to `facebook.com/home.php` (even though the 'next' parameter is set to my site) and the User is still not logged out when I visit my site again...

Here is the code...(Facebook library is autoloaded thru the Codeigniter Configuration)

```
public function DestroySession()
{
        $this->load->helper('url');

if($this->facebook->getUser())
{
    $this->facebook->destroySession();


    $logout = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array("next" => "http://mysite.com/"));


    redirect($logout, 'location', 301);
}
 }
```

So I got this to finally work. You can see the new function below. For some reasons that I am not entirely sure about you have to do these steps.

```
public function DestroySession()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');



//Get User ID
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();

if ($user)
{
    try
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
       $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');

   //   print_r($user_profile);
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {

        log_message('eror', $e);

        $user = null;
    }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user)
{
if( session_id() ){} else { session_start() ; }

    $logoutUrl = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params = array('next' => base_url()));
    //echo 'Logout; '.($logoutUrl);
    $this->facebook->destroySession();
    redirect($logoutUrl, 'refresh');



}
}
```

Comment: Is it working if you remove the `next` parameter?

Comment: No, does the same thing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why using `301`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my orignal question for more context.

```
public function DestroySession()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');



//Get User ID
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();

if ($user)
{
    try
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
       $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');

   //   print_r($user_profile);
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {

        log_message('eror', $e);

        $user = null;
    }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user)
{
if( session_id() ){} else { session_start() ; }

    $logoutUrl = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params = array('next' => base_url()));
    //echo 'Logout; '.($logoutUrl);
    $this->facebook->destroySession();
    redirect($logoutUrl, 'refresh');



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do with Javascript using a link like this:

```
<a href="/logout" onclick="FB.logout();">Logout</a>
```

This first calls the onclick function and performs a logout on facebook, and then the normal /logout function of my site is called. I would prefer a server-side solution as well, it logs me out on both sites.

Check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: This is another approach that will work, but I wanted to stay consistent with using the PHP SDK.